Find the $m\angle EAD$ in the triangle below
Let the squares $ABCD$ and $EFGC$ be such that: $G$, $E$ and $D$ are collinear $GE = ED$.
Calculate the $m\angle EAD$
(E is external to the square ABCD)
(Answer:$26,5^o$ )
I try:
Without loss of generality $CG = 1 \implies EG = \sqrt2 = ED$
$\triangle DCG:CD^2 = DG^2+CG^2-2DG.CG,cos45^o$
$CD^2 =(2\sqrt2)^2+1^2-2.(2\sqrt2)(1).\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=9-4 = 5$
$\therefore  CD = \sqrt5=AD$\
$\triangle ADE: AD^2 = AE^2+ED^2 - 2AE.ED. cos45^o$
$(\sqrt5)^2 = AE^2+(\sqrt2)^2-2AE.\sqrt2.\frac{\sqrt2}{2} = AE^2-2-2AE$
$AE^2-2AE-7=0 \implies AE = 1-2\sqrt2 \vee AE = 1+2\sqrt2$
$\triangle ADE: ED^2 = AD^2+AE^2-2AD.AE.cos \angle DAE(=\theta)$
$(\sqrt2)^2=(\sqrt5)^2+(1+2\sqrt2)^2-2(\sqrt5)(1+2\sqrt2)cos \theta$
$2 = 5+1+4\sqrt2+8 - 2\sqrt5-4\sqrt{10}cos \theta \implies$
$cos \theta = \frac{-(-12-4\sqrt2+2\sqrt5)} {4\sqrt10}. \frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{10}} \implies$
$Cos \theta = \frac{12\sqrt{10}+4\sqrt{20}-2\sqrt{50}}{40} = \frac{6\sqrt{10}+10\sqrt{5}-5\sqrt{2}}{20}$


One approach: Since $EG$ is the diagonal of a square, and $DE=EG$, we can construct a square on diagonal $DE$ congruent to that on $EG$. Moreover, we can fill in yet another congruent square adjoining them (below $EC$, call the extension on $GC$ $X$) such that $DC$ is the diagonal of a $2x1$ rectangle. Note that $\angle{DAE}=\angle{CDX}$, and its value is $\arctan{\frac{1}{2}} \approx 26.5$.


Let $M$ be the midpoint of $CD$. Draw line $AM$ and then $CE$ perpendicular to it. Construct from $C$ the line parallel to $AE$, meeting line $DE$ at $G$.
By similar triangles ($DEM\sim DGC$) we get $CG=2EM$ and $EG=ED$. By similar triangles ($CEM\sim ADM$) we also get $CE=2EM$, hence $CE=CG$ and you can complete $ECG$ to a square, thus constructing the given figure.
It follows that $\tan\theta={1\over2}$.
